# Automatically refresh page after click update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can i refresh automatically the page after i edited the data in mysqli. I had already implement the reload function as shown below but it does not work.

```
$('#insert').click(function() { location.reload(); });
```

I want to make it like once i click update the data, the page will show the updated data otherwise i will have to click refresh to show the updated data.

```
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<?php
include('../connect.php');

// Attempt query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `applicant`";
$result = mysqli_query($Conndb, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row["FULL_NAME"]. "</td>" .
         "<td>". $row["IC_NO"]. "</td>" .
         "<td>". $row["AGE"]. "</td>" .
         "<td>". $row["GENDER"]. "</td>" .
         "<td>". $row["CONTACT"]. "</td>" .
         "<td>
         <a href=\"active.php? id=" . $row['APPLICANT_ID'] . "\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are yousure?'); \">Activate</a></td>" ?>
         <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $row["APPLICANT_ID"]; ?>" class=btn btn-info btn-xs view_data"></td>
         <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="edit" id="<?php echo $row["APPLICANT_ID"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data"></td>
    <?php echo "</tr>"; ?>

    <script>  
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#insert').click(function() { 
          location.reload();
        }); 


       $('#add').click(function(){  
        $('#insert').val("Insert");  
        $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
       });
       $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
         var applicant_id = $(this).attr("id");  

         $.ajax({  
           url:"selected.php",  
           method:"POST",  
           data:{applicant_id:applicant_id},  
           success:function(data){  
            $('#applicant_detail').html(data);  
            $('#dataModal').modal('show');  
          }  
        });  

       }); 

       $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
         var applicant_id = $(this).attr("id");  
         $.ajax({  
            url:"fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{applicant_id:applicant_id},  
            dataType:"json",  
            success:function(data){  
              $('#name').val(data.FULL_NAME);
              $('#ic').val(data.IC_NO);
              $('#gender').val(data.GENDER);
              $('#age').val(data.AGE);
              $('#nationality').val(data.NATIONALITY);
              $('#race').val(data.RACE);
              $('#other_race').val(data.OTHER_RACE);
              $('#address').val(data.ADDRESS);
              $('#contact').val(data.CONTACT);
              $('#marital_status').val(data.MARITAL_STATUS);
              $('#property').val(data.PROPERTY);
              $('#monthly_rent').val(data.MONTHLY_RENT);
              $('#working_or_not').val(data.WORKINGORNOT);
              $('#applicant_id').val(data.APPLICANT_ID);  
              $('#insert').val("Update");  
              $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
           }  
         });  
       }); 

      $('#insert').click(function() { 
        location.reload();
      });

      $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
        event.preventDefault();  
        if($('#name').val() == "") {  
         alert("Name is required");  
        } else {  
          $.ajax({  
            url:"insert.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),  
            beforeSend:function(){  
              $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
            }, 
            success:function(data){  
              $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
              $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
              $('#employee_table').html(data);  
            }  
          });  
        }  
      }); 

     });  
   </script>

   <?php  
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

//Close connection
mysqli_close($Conndb);
?>
```

Comment: you will have to broadcast the event and catch it in your view and then write the code for reloading in it..

Comment: You are using ajax post request to insert data,and ajax is usually used to do not reload page and request execute.

Comment: Offtopic: unless `$row['APPLICANT_ID']` is `insert` you have no element with an id of `insert` on your page. Html element ids need to be unique, you have three elements with the same id (`$row["APPLICANT_ID"]`)